# javascript add and remove input value

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

there was a ton of different ways I seen to do this here on stackoverflow. However, I have tried them and can't get it to work.

Here is my current code.

http://jsfiddle.net/tech0925/C9Z8N/5/

Here is the javascript

```
function printcardCheck() {
       if (document.getElementById('print_card').checked) {
            document.getElementById('printvoucher-receiver').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('printvoucher-receiver').style.padding = '10px 0 0 0';
            document.getElementById('print_cards').value = 'Add this value';
        } 
                   else document.getElementById('printvoucher-receiver').style.display = 'none';
}
```

See the fiddle link above.

Comment: What is your expected result? I mean, there is no element with id `giftvoucher-receiver`, and you haven't even defined `mailcardCheck()`.

Comment: Hi, sorry abou that. That was other code that I did not bring over. I updated my code and fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Y4YNs/

I believe you want to do something like this. I will change it to native JS later.

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="set1" value="A">A</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="set1" value="B">B</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="set1" value="C">C</label>
</form>
<div class="more" id="A">Some more options for A</div>
<div class="more" id="B">Some more options for B</div>
<div class="more" id="C">Some more options for C</div>
```

```
$("form input").change(function () {
    $(".more").removeClass("show")
        .filter("#" + $(this).val()).addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: This would not work for me. I need to use the input tag to carry over the data when the form is submitted. Also, I want to add the value when clicked and remove the value if another option is clicked so the value does not get submitted.

Comment: @MagentoMan - You don't have to use `value` as indicating which options to be shown. You can use whatever attribute you like. Also you can use `switch` in the `change` listener to execute specific commands upon different options checked.

Comment: Can you take a look at my fiddle and see if you can make it add the value on click and remove it if another option is clicked instead?

Comment: @MagentoMan - If you do not want jQuery I can change it to native JavaScript.

Comment: I added it to my site but it does not want to work. Can you provide the javascript example? Thanks!

Comment: @MagentoMan - Yea you will have to include jQuery if you use `$`.

Comment: Well it was actually due to a prototype.js conflict so I defined it as var $$ = jQuery; which fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

there should only be one tag that id is 'print_card',and you have two,so when getElementById('print_card') will return the first one, that is the radio

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the code and fiddle but it still does not work.